# Display post metadata: "title, category, author, date" with shortcode

Tags: shortcode, post-meta

How to create shortcodes to the standard post-metadata "title, author, category and date" in order to display it in post-content?

E.g. post-content including shorcodes: Lorem ipsum dolor **[post_title]** sit amet, **[post_category]** consectetur adipiscing elit **[post_author]**..

Followed this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079490/how-to-include-page-title-of-wordpress-post-in-the-content-possibly-with-a-short) and it worked for the title but can't make it work on the other metadata: category, author name and date. The code is the following:

function myshortcode_title( ){
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are outside the loop then you can use to get them by post id, you can play around with these snippet:

shortcode for author's name:

```
function author_name_shortcode(){
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $author = get_the_author($post_id);
    return $author;
}
add_shortcode('post_author','author_name_shortcode');
```

shortcode for categories name:

```
function category_name_shortcode(){
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $catName = "";
    foreach((get_the_category($post_id)) as $category){
        $catName .= $category->name . " ,";
    }
    return $catName;
}
add_shortcode('post_category','category_name_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually inside your theme. For post options you can decide which meta data you'd like displayed. If your theme doesn't offer these options then you might consider using a more extensive theme like Genesis